# mysql select count(*) results in Data too long for column

Tags: mysql, count

I am running a count(*) on a view, but I get the following error. The view has several joins and views. But this error should only apply when changing a value on a table field, right?

```
mysql> select count(*) from dm.vSscore24 ;                                             

ERROR 1406 (22001): Data too long for column 'pbs' at row 1
mysql>

db info
mysql> show variables like '%version%';
+-------------------------+-----------------------------+
| Variable_name           | Value                       |
+-------------------------+-----------------------------+
| innodb_version          | 5.7.20                      |
| protocol_version        | 10                          |
| slave_type_conversions  |                             |
| tls_version             | TLSv1,TLSv1.1               |
| version                 | 5.7.20-0ubuntu0.16.04.1-log |
| version_comment         | (Ubuntu)                    |
| version_compile_machine | x86_64                      |
| version_compile_os      | Linux                       |
+-------------------------+-----------------------------+
```

thank you.

Comment: Does the view(s) contain any user defined variables?

Comment: hi @P.Salmon . no, but it did call some functions, with small variable sizes.

thank you for your comment

Comment: @P.Salmon views can't contain MySQL user variables. `CREATE VIEW test AS SELECT @test CROSS JOIN (SELECT @test := 'test') AS init_user_params;` wil generate a SQL error `Error Code: 1351
View's SELECT contains a variable or parameter`

Answer (score 0):

**found** the issue.

It was a function called inside a view that had a variable (named *pbshape*) too small for the maximum size of the column.

Luckily there were no columns named '*pbs*' anywhere (in tables or views), and that made me wonder.
If the variable were named like *bs* I think I would never have found the answer :P

The word column in the error message 'Data too long for column' is extremely missleading.

thank you guys

Comment: Nice next time also post de code of the view and the function then we can help you better... Well the variable @pbshape will be rendered as a column within MySQL engine so the error `Data too long for column` isn't really missleading.